# London School of Geometry and Number Theory application question

Tags: career-development

The London School of Geometry and Number Theory is essentially a graduate school offering PhD programmes in the above areas and it it a joint effort of Imperial, KCL and UCL. My question is, should I apply for a position in the LSGNT, is it normal (advisable?) to apply for PhD positions in the 3 universities separately as well, given that some potential PhD supervisors in Imperial, KCL or UCL are also project supervisors in LSGNT? Sorry if the question is irrelevant.

Comment: Yes, apply separately

Comment: Even better, get in touch with the faculty… they will 100% respond to you. GL!